# Why groups are create in Linux/Unix?

Tags: linux

I'm trying to understand linux commands, but some commands of linux are flying over my head one of them is, why groups are created in linux whats that purpose?

Comment: Hello and welcome on StackExchange Unix&Linux, please take the time to read the [tour]. Questions related to tutorials or basic explanation are not really on topic here. Basically groups are usefull to seperate users in groups with different right. but groups exist in any OS and is a basic concept, you should maybe try to find complete documentation about operating systems such as : https://github.com/concerttttt/books/blob/master/Modern%20Operating%20Systems%204th%20Edition--Andrew%20Tanenbaum.pdf

Comment: The same reason we have "user and "other": to set permissions. So to allow or disallow actions on a server.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that Unixes are multi-user systems by origin. With that in mind, something like system shared between the students and faculty of a university might very well have use for dividing the users to different groups. You could have usage limits set up on the system, and you might want for the students to have stricter limits than the staff has. You might also have a separate computing cluster that's only accessible to those who actually need it (and know how to use it), that could be another group. (I'm assuming a shared user database here, but that's pretty much a necessity when you have multiple systems.)

As for file permissions, you might have a directory for some project and a group that has access to the directory so they can modify the files (a proper `umask` setting and the `setgid` bit on directories help here).

Out of all the staff, you would have a smaller set of people who are allowed to gain superuser access on the system. One way to do that is to use file permissions to only allow members of a particular group (often `root` or `wheel`) to run `su`.
`sudo` would be more common on current Linuxes, but it's  also configured to use groups to determine who can do what.

---

Now, of course multiuser systems where you login with a serial terminal / telnet / SSH aren't that common any more. But if your system runs any services that are usable by others outside the system, it's useful to partition them into *user accounts* of their own. Groups can then be used to allow limited access between the users. For example, `crontab` is a setgid binary and uses group permissions to get access to the `crontab` files, and you could have a `www-data` group that would be allowed to modify the data files of an HTTP server. (Or the other way round, the user files could be given read permission for `www-data` so the HTTP server can read them.)

Comment: can u summarized it in short details?

Answer (score -1):

groups will help to assign permission like sudo group(which will have root access)

so whenever you want to assign permission some roles for anyuser , just add into any groups as per your requirement